# How to incorporate ->isDirty() with laravel ->update()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to check if certain columns in database are changed.

the update code in my controller goes like this:

```
$tCustomer = TCustomer::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);

$tCustomer->update(request()->all());
```

How do I incorporate it with the ->isDirty() function?

I tried adding it after `$tCustomer->update(request()->all());` but it always returns false:

```
$dirty = $tCustomer->getDirty('payment_method_id');
```

do I have to add isDirty() before or right after the update?

Comment: i fall in this problem and i think this is the strangest thing that i experience in laravel

Answer (score 12):

You can use `fill()` instead of `update()`, check for `isDirty()`, then `save()`. This way you can take advantage of the mass injectable fields.

```
$myModel->fill($arrayLikeinUpdate);
if ($myModel->isDirty()) {
    // do something
}
$myModel->save();
```

Comment: when i update it its not worked and isdirty() method returned false .. but when use fill this worked. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers), you can use [updating()](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_updating) eloquent model event for before saving the model or [updated()](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_updated) after saving model, you just have to add below code in your `TCustomer` model:

```
public static function boot(){
    static::updated(function($tCustomer){
        if($tCustomer->isDirty('field_name')){
           //This code will run only after model save and field_name is updated, You can do whatever you want like triggering event etc.
        }
    }
    static::updating(function($tCustomer){
    if($tCustomer->isDirty('field_name')){
       //This code will run only before saving model and field_name is updating, You can do whatever you want like triggering event etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

`isDirty` returns a bool,  so you'd use it with a conditional to check if a given models attributes have changed. Example:

```
 // modify an attribute
 $myModel->foo = 'some new value';

 ....
 // do other stuff
 ...

 // before the model has been saved
 if ($myModel->isDirty()) {
      // update model
      $myModel->save();
 }
```

So the check needs to be done before you update (save) the model.

Calling `update` saves the model with the given attributes in one call so you wouldn't use `isDirty` in that context.

Comment: Not what was asked.